# Push to array of struct type gives an error. Is it related to storage mechanisms of the solidity?

Tags: arrays, struct

I'm new to the solidity language. I have seen similar codes that works(with same solidity version), but my code

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.8;

contract Test{
    struct History{
        uint256 id;
        uint256[] people;
    }

    History[] private history;

    History history_var = History(1, [1,2]);

    history.push(history_var);

    function getHistory() external view returns(History[] memory) {
        return history;
    }
    
}
```

gives following error:

```
ParserError: Expected identifier but got '('
  --> contracts/test.sol:14:17:
   |
14 |     history.push(history_var);
   |                 ^
```

From my research it looks like it can be related to how `history` is stored. However I was not able to figure out what is the exact problem and how to fix it.

Comment: solidity doesn't work like this, any operation should be included in a function, unlike JS.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a constructor for running your initialisation code. You are also creating an [array literal](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.24/types.html#array-literals) of type `uint256[2]` instead of a [dynamic-length, in-memory array](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.24/types.html#allocating-memory-arrays) `uint256[]` that happens to hold two values. This snippet will compile and do what you wanted:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.8;

contract Test{
    struct History{
        uint256 id;
        uint256[] people;
    }

    History[] private history;
    
    constructor() {
        uint256[] memory people = new uint256[](2);
        people[0] = 1;
        people[1] = 2;
        history.push(History(1, people));
    }

    function getHistory() external view returns(History[] memory) {
        return history;
    }
    
}
```